# Error on line to add data to struct (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

Error on line to add data

I have two Error

How can i fix that?

---

**First Error**

[image]

**Second Error**

[image]

---

**var entities = Entity**

**My Struct:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
struct Entity : Codable  {
    var cname: String
    var barcode: String
    var cardnbr: String
}
```

**Add data:**

```
let aEntity = Entity(cname: CompanyName, barcode:BarCodeField, cardnbr: CardNumber)   

if var all :[Entity] = LoadData() {

    all.append(aEntity)     

    SaveData(allData: all)

} else {

    SaveData(allData: [aEntity])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var entities = [Entity] = []
```

to

```
var entities = [Entity]()
```

**2nd Error:**

There is no need to write Codable methods in this case since you used same variable name as JSON object keys.
Just remove `enum CodingKeys` , `init(from`  & `encode(to`

Credits to vadian. :)

Comment: But how fix 1 Error?

Comment: @B2Fq create an Extension for the Entity. And Conforms Codable Protocol there. Check my answer

Comment: @LalKrishna No, delete both `init(from` and `encode(to`. You get them for free.

Comment: Oops. I forgot that. :(

Answer (score 2):

**First error**

Declare the struct as

```
struct Entity : Codable  {
    var cname: String
    var barcode: String
    var cardnbr: String
}
```

No `CodingKeys`, no `init(from`, no `encode(to`

**Second error**

Declare the array as

```
var entities = [Entity]()
```

Comment: The load and save methods in your previous question are supposed to work. And please – once again – remove the `do - catch` block. Don't you see the yellow warning?